# Why table doesn't allow more then one clustered index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Generally SQL Server table allows only one clustered index. Can you please explain what is internal architecture behind that?

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You most likely say "SQL" and really mean "SQL Server" - the Microsoft RDBMS. Be more specific! **SQL Server** does have the concept of clustered index - other SQL-based RDBMS do not.

Comment: I suggest you peruse [Tables and Index Data Structures Architecture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180978%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clustered index dictates the physical order of the records in a table. 
So you cannot have two or more clustered indexes; the records are stored just once. The primary key constraint automatically creates a clustered index and lays out the data in the table, according to the column(s) it comprises.

The non-clustered indexes are ones that represent just a view of the data in the table - i.e., the data is sorted *logically*. That's why you can have as many non-clustered indexes as you wish but only one clustered one.

Answer (score 2):

A clustered index means that the data is actually sorted on the data pages based on the column/columns in the clustered index.

The data is only stored once, so it can only be sorted once.  Hence, only one clustered is allowed.

In general, any number of other indexes are allowed, so this is not a serious limitation.